# Flutter/Dart Datatable or Sliver with fixed header and fixed row header

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want to create a data view for a Flutter app that incorporates a datatable or sliver (or anything really) with a fixed header when scrolling vertically and also fixed row headers when scrolling horizontally. I tried messing around with the [data_table_2](https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2) and [table_sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/table_sticky_headers) plugins, but they don't do exactly what I want. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction or help come up with a solution.

Here's a gif image showing what I want to achieve...

[Data View Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Musx.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was pretty simple actually, using nested Stack's and SingleChildScrollView's. No plug-ins required.

Here's a link to the example source code if anyone is interested...

https://github.com/jstoyles/flutter_data_view_idea

Answer (score 0):

In my case I handle this way.Maybe it will be helpful for someone

```
RawScrollbar(
                  radius: Radius.circular(16.r),
                  thickness: 6,
                  trackVisibility: true,
                  scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
                  thumbColor: KColor.white.color,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20.w,
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.w),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(4.r),
                              ),
                              color: KColor.tableHader.color,
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: List.generate(
                                  controller.tableHeader!.length, (index) {
                                if (index == 0) {
                                  return GlobalText(
                                    str: "",
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Container(
                                    margin: index == 4
                                        ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 65.w)
                                        : EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: 30.w),
                                    child: GlobalText(
                                      str: controller.tableHeader![index]
                                          .toString(),
                                      color: KColor.black.color,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      fontFamily: AppConstant.AROBIA_BOOK.key,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                              }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Theme(
                              data: ThemeData().copyWith(
                                dividerColor: KColor.white.color,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.w),
                                    child: DataTable(
                                      horizontalMargin: 0,
                                      showBottomBorder: true,
                                      dataRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        KColor.white.color,
                                      ),
                                      headingRowColor:
                                          MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        KColor.white.color,
                                      ),
                                      headingRowHeight: 0.h,
                                      dataRowHeight: 60.h,
                                      showCheckboxColumn: false,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: KColor.white.color,
                                      ),
                                      columnSpacing: 40.w,
                                      columns: List.generate(
                                        controller.tableHeader!.length,
                                        (index) => DataColumn(
                                          label: SizedBox.shrink(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      rows: List.generate(
                                          controller.tableRow!.length, (index) {
                                        return TransactionHistoryTableRow
                                            .tableDataRow(
                                          context: context,
                                          index: index,
                                          tableRow: controller.tableRow,
                                        );
                                      }),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20.h,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```